# How to loop over a complex JSON in return in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am learning Reactjs while building a simple application. I know this is very basic and there are alot of answers for the same question available on stackoverflow. But i am unable to implement those maybe because of variable scopes. I would be grateful if someone is able to help me out with this.

My full code is pretty complex and irrelevant to the question. But please refer to this fiddle : [Full Code](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49598/). This will work in local server.

Relevant Code:

```
var localStore = {};
// localStore = {"f":{"symbol":"f","quantity":10,"pricePaid":136},"jnj":{"symbol":"jnj","quantity":30,"pricePaid":146}};

var SearchStock = React.createClass({
...
render: function() {
...
return ( // I tried map function in other ways too like [localstore].map and then get its values in similar way as i am getting below.
{/*localStore.map(function (l, i) {
  return <tr>
           <td>{Object.keys(l)[i].symbol}</td>
           <td>{Object.keys(l)[i].quantity}</td>
           <td>{Object.keys(l)[i].pricePaid}</td>
           <td>{Object.keys(l)[i].symbol}</td>
         </tr>
})*/}
{/*for(var x in localStorage){ // This is what i really want to do.
  return <tr>
           <td>{x.symbol}</td>
           <td>{x.quantity}</td>
           <td>{x.pricePaid}</td>
           <td>anything</td>
         </tr>
}*/}
{stocks.map(function(l) { // this works.
   console.log("in return stocks",JSON.stringify(stocks));
   return <tr>
            <td>{l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["name"]}</td>
            <td>{this.state.quantity}</td>
            <td>{this.state.pricePaid}</td>
            <td>{<input type="button" value="View Stock"/>}</td>
          </tr>
}, this)}
```

I don't know why map function didn't work as value in localStore and stocks is similar: `stocks = [{only one key pair of localStore}]`. I would appreciate any help or guidance i can get for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Object.keys` to get an array with the keys of `localStore` and iterate through it to display your data.

```
{Object.keys(localStore).map(function (key) {
          return <tr key={key}>
              <td>{localStore[key].symbol}</td>
              <td>{localStore[key].quantity}</td>
              <td>{localStore[key].pricePaid}</td>
              <td>{localStore[key].symbol}</td>
          </tr>
 })}
```

You were missing other things like

1º Provide a key to every child in the array.

2º Wrap your `<tr>` tags inside a `<tbody>`.  `<tr>` cannot appear as a child of `<table>`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49602/)